# What RegEx pattern to use for URL rewrite to redirect traffic to HTTPS, but not from a particular subdomain?

Tags: url-rewriting, iis-7, windows-server-2008, url-rewrite-module

Just got our SSL certificate installed and we want to redirect traffic to https. Running IIS 7 on Windows Server 2008 using URL Rewrite module, we want to redirect traffic to the secure protocol, but not from a particular subdomain.

For example:

mydomain.com and www.mydomain.com, we want to redirect to HTTPS

However, admin.mydomain.com, we want to leave on the HTTP protocol

[This is the example I followed](https://www.sslshopper.com/iis7-redirect-http-to-https.html) . I set up an inbound rule and the matching the URL pattern I'm using is:

```
^(?!(admin).*).*$
```

This redirects traffic from the domain, but it's also redirecting traffic from admin.mydomain.com, which we don't want. What pattern would I use to redirect all traffic, except for a particular subdomain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to remove what you have and keep the rule from the example, then add one more condition like below. Negate=true ensures the rules matches everything except the domain you want to exclude:

```
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" pattern="^admin.mydomain.com$"/>
```